# Invoking the app bar in Windows 8 app causes scrolled child divs to jump to top

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I've encountered an odd behavior in a Windows8 app that I'm building with WinJS, javascript, and HTML.  In a particular Page that I'm implementing, there are several divs that have CSS rules like this:

```
.col {
  border: 1px solid none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is when I invoke the main app bar by right clicking, the scrolled content in the div snaps to the top of the div.  In other words, the scroll position of the div is lost.  I've tried a host of ways to fix, but nothing has come up.  How can I prevent the scrolled content from jumping around upon invoking the App Bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

suggest to use -ms-grid for the page. The app bar will overlap the div in that case, which is ok and likely right behavior that you can see in other apps also.

html:

```
<div class="test5 fragment">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle">test page</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section class="content" aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div class="test-content">
            Text here.
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar">
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmd', label:'Command', icon:'placeholder'}" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.test5.fragment section[role=main] {
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Alternately I would check the z-index on your div that you are showing - most likely it is not absolutely displayed so its just pushing it out of the way when a new element comes into display.

Answer (score 0):

@Sushil is correct. AppBar is an overlay control, so you should place it next to the fragment div, not inside it. @Sushil's code shows how to do it.

Placing an appbar inside the fragment has performance penalties as it will need to be rendered every time a user navigates to that page. Another undesirable side effect is that all input to the appbar will propagate to the fragment. This is the problem you are facing.

In theory, you can listen to the various input events for mouse, keyboard, touch and call preventDefault on them. But it is not recommended.